# How can I save temporary file in .NET MAUI?

Tags: .net, maui, maui-blazor

How to store a temporary file in a .NET MAUI application which runs on Windows, IOS, and Android?

And how to retrieve its path?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to manage temporary files using .NET Maui is to use the built-in file system helpers found in the Microsoft.Maui.Storage namespace. These helpers will give you a path that is valid on the device that your code is running on. For temporary files you may want to consider using the path that FileSystem.CacheDirectory returns.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers

Answer (score 0):

You can use **File Handling**.

For more information about it, you can refer to [File Handling in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=macos)

You can use this tool to save the data in a file. It is also effective in .NET MAUI projects.

Files are generated on all three platforms, and they can be extracted at any time.

I wrote an example for your reference. Here is the background code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "temp.txt");//address
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void mytest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, "aaaaazxczxcsaaaazxvcvmaaaaaaaa"); //save
    }
    private async void mycheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Alert", File.ReadAllText(fileName), "OK"); //read
    }
}
```

Comment: This code seems working with no errors, but it's actually doing nothing. No files are created, nor content has been updated.

Comment: 1) @ElieTebchrani - which platform are you testing on? 2) Test first with an all-lower-case filename, and no sub-directory: `string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "temp.txt");`. 3) If you follow the link in answer, then browse code link, eventually leads you to [Working with files](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/WorkingWithFiles/WorkingWithFiles), the complete Xamarin Forms sample.